# how do I the functionality of add new friends reject and delete friend in my user app using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I Want to add features such as Add Friend, Send Friend Request, Accept Friend Requests features in my Django website

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args,**kwargs)

            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

kindly help me out to add friends request functionalities to my project as I'm new to Django,  help me out how I should proceed with
this code further add the mentioned functionalities to my project.

Comment: Thank you:) it would be more helpful if you help to add functionalities @Sumithran

Comment: Building these features is as simple as user creation. You just need to design your db according to your requirement (For example, create a FriendRequest table with `from_user` (User Instance) `to_user` (User Instance), `status`(Choice field with Accepted, Rejected, Pending, etc), `created`, and `modified` dates and create the views accordingly). This may help you to get an idea -> https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/add-friends-with-689a2fa4e41d

Answer (score 0):

There's a package  called django-friendship.

This enables you to create and manage follows, blocks and bi-directional friendships between users. It features:

Friendship request objects that can be accepted, rejected, canceled, or marked as viewed.

Hooks to easily list all friend requests sent or received by a given user, filtered by the status of the request.

A blocklist for each user of users they've blocked.

Tags to include information about friendships, blocks and follows in your templates.

Integration with AUTH_USER_MODEL.Validation to prevent common mistakes.Faster server response time through caching

https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship